# Подтверждение при закрытии формы

Tags: java, swing

На SWING написал небольшое меню и теперь вопрос как сделать что бы при нажатии на крестик или при выборе пункта меню "Exit" выполнялось одно и тоже действие

Сейчас у меня дублируются два класса MyAction и MyWindowAction

Как сделать оптимально?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    
    static JFrame frame = getFrame();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        
        JMenuBar jmenuBar = new JMenuBar();
        
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");             
        
        JMenuItem menuExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        menuExit.addActionListener(new MyAction());
        fileMenu.add(menuExit);     
        
        jmenuBar.add(fileMenu);     
                
        frame.setJMenuBar(jmenuBar);
        frame.revalidate();
        
        frame.addWindowListener(new MyWindowAction());      
        
    }
    
    static class MyAction extends  AbstractAction{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                    "Close?", "Exit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
        if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
           System.exit(1);
           frame.dispose();        }
            
        }
    }
    
    static class MyWindowAction extends WindowAdapter{
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.windowClosing(e);

            int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                    "Close?", "Exit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
        if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
           System.exit(1);
           frame.dispose();        }
            
        }
        }   

    static JFrame getFrame() {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Моя первая программа SWING");
        
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dimension = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        
        frame.setBounds(dimension.width /2 -250, dimension.height/2 - 150, 500, 300);
        
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        return frame;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать отдельный статический метод:

```
class Main {
    static void exit() {
        int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                    "Close?", "Exit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
        if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
           System.exit(0); 
           frame.dispose();        
        }            
    }
    
    static class MyAction extends  AbstractAction{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            exit();
        }            
    }
    
    static class MyWindowAction extends WindowAdapter{
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            exit();
        }
    }   
}
```